# Как создать шаблон, который отвечает требованию: строка не может начинаться или заканчиваться символом "-"

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Как регулярными выражениями создать шаблон, который отвечает требованию: строка не может начинаться или заканчиваться символов "-"?

Comment: а причем здесь питон, если вопрос про регулряки? )

Comment: я просто не знаю отличаются ли регулярки в разных языках. т.к. мне они нужны в питоне соответственно я поставил метку python.

Comment: Вашему условию соответствует регулярка /^[^-].*[^-]$/

Сомневаюсь, что сами регулярки отличаются в разных языках. Просто некоторые языки могут не поддерживать некоторые разновидности.

Про разновидности можно почитать [здесь](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Comment: А имеет ли смысл использовать регулярные выражения, чтобы проверить начинается или заканчивается строка одним символом?

    if s and s[0] != '-' and s[-1] != '-':

Comment: @LinnTroll, имеет) если задание учебное - то ваш ответ ни капли не поможет)

вопрос же был - не как что-то проверить, а как это что-то проверить используя именно регулярки

Comment: @BOPOH это может быть полезно не только для образования, например, какая-нибудь система (как раньше поиск кода в гугле), может позволять вводить regex, чтобы найти записи, не позволяя ничего другого. Следует указать, что regex это не лучшее решение, но следует также ответить на вопрос с поставленными ограничениями, для людей, которым удобней regex использовать.

Answer (score 2):

Регулярные выражения не нужны, чтобы определить не начинается и не заканчивается ли строка на `'-'`:

```
def cond(text):
    return not (text.startswith('-') or text.endswith('-'))
```

Если нужны именно регулярные выражения, то проще выразить обратное условие: строка начинается или заканчивается на `'-'`, а затем обратить условие в коде:

```
import re

def cond(text):
    return not re.search(r'\A\-|\-\Z', text)
```

Прямое условие (либо пустая строка, либо единственный символ (не `'-'`), либо строка, которая начинается с не `'-'` символа, за которым следует ноль или более любых символов и заканчивается на не `'-'` символ):

```
def cond(text):
    return re.search('^$|^[^-]$|^[^-].*[^-]$', text, flags=re.DOTALL) is not None
```

`re.DOTALL` используется для поддержки многострочного текста (с `'\n'`).

Можно упростить выражение, если использовать lookahead assertions:

```
def cond(text):
    return re.fullmatch(r'(?:[^-]|(?<!\A)-(?!\Z))*', text) is not None
```

regex говорит, что строка состоит из нуля или более не `'-'` символов либо `'-'` символов, которые не находятся ни в начале, ни в конце строки.

Answer (score 1):

Подытожу комментарии к вопросу. В регулярке мы описываем шаблон строки `^[^-].+[^-]$` – непустая строка, которая не начитается и не заканчивается на символ '-', если строка может быть пустой, в шаблоне нужно `.+` поменять на `.*`.

Если результат `re.search` не равен `None` – строка совпадает с шаблоном, иначе -- совпадает:

```
import re


def check(text):
    if not text.strip():
        return True

    return re.search('^[^-].*[^-]$', text) is not None

print(check('abc'))    # True
print(check('-abc'))   # False
print(check('-abc-'))  # False
print(check('abc-'))   # False
print(check(' '))      # True
```

Но такая простая проверка не требует регулярок, и проще (и лучше) использовать сравнение по первому и последнему символу строки:

```
>>> def check(text):
        if not text:
            return True

        return text[0] != '-' and text[-1] != '-'
...
>>> check('abc-')
False
>>> check('-abc-')
False
>>> check('-abc')
False
>>> check('abc')
True
>>> check('')
True
```

Comment: это не верно, например, `''` строка не начинается, не заканчивается на `-`, но как `'^[^-].+[^-]$'` так и `text[0] != '-' and text[-1] != '-'` ломаются в этом случае.

Comment: я не стал писать в ответе, что автор соответственно должен проверять размеры строки (это и так понятно, ведь правда?), но для регулярок написал, что для пустых строк использовать `.*`

Comment: *"это и так понятно, ведь правда?"* -- подавляющее большинство вопросов и так понятны -- зачем тогда на них отвечать? Если ваш ответ не работает для строк менее чем три символа, то следует это явно указать (лучше всего, просто привести решение, которое для всех строк работает).