# Паттерн на отсутствие строки в тексте

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Добрый день. Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать паттерн на отсутствие определенной конструкции в тексте с помощью регулярных выражений в Python? 
Программа оценивает сложность пароля, если в строке пароле отсутствует набор символов похожий на дату, примерно так:

```
r'\d[.-]\d{2}[.-]\d'
```

то сложность пароля оценивается выше. Но так как это единственный антипаттерн среди других условий, хотелось бы чтобы re.search() выдавал результат именно при отсутствии, а не при наличии.
Пример кода:

```
    password_strength = 0
    pattern = [r'\d', r'\W', r'\d[.-]\d{2}[.-]\d', r'\d{11}']
    for pattern in patterns:
        if re.search(pattern, password):
            password_strength += 2
```

Comment: Негативный просмотр вперед `r'(?!.*\d{2,4}[.-]\d{2}[.-]\d{2,4})'` пробуйте. Не знаю как search сработает правда.

Comment: @Visman search сработал так же как и на r'\d[.-]\d{2}[.-]\d'

Comment: связанный вопрос [Как создать шаблон, который отвечает требованию: строка не может начинаться или заканчиваться символом "-"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/301265/23044)

Comment: в сторону: [Password Rules Are Bullshit](https://blog.codinghorror.com/password-rules-are-bullshit/)

Comment: Меня лично бесит, когда "особо умные" программисты требуют от меня ввести буквы, цифры, регистры, символы, в итоге мой стандартный пароль из 18 буквоцифр, который я набираю за несколько секунд не удовлетворяет "требованиям безопасности". А улыбать начинает, когда наложив кучу запретов эти самые люди позволяют создать пароль 6 знаков или менее.

Comment: @jfs не помогла ссылка. Насчет password rules are Bullshit - учебная задача, ничего не могу поделать.

Comment: *"не помогла ссылка"* — не очень информативно. Какие из трёх предложенных по ссылке re-решений вы пробовали, что ожидали получить и что вместо этого происходит (опишите подробно, с полным, но минимальным примером кода и соответствующим вводом/выводом, [mcve])

Comment: @jfs никакие не пробовал, так как не понимаю в принципе как использовать приведенные вами решения в моем случае

Comment: если *"не понимаю в принципе"*, то спрашивайте.  К примеру, что не ясно с `not re.search()` вариантом? (у вас готовое regex прямо в вопросе есть: подменили одно на другое регулярное выражение -- вот вам и ответ)

Comment: @jfs `not` не получиться вставить потому что надо второе условие создавать. Вопрос в том как сделать именно антипаттерн,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Отрицание в коде

Самый простой, надёжный, лёгкий для понимания и последующих изменений вариант — это обратить условие в коде:

```
not_found = not re.search(antipattern, text)
```

то есть разделить правила на две группы: что может присутствовать в тексте и что не должно присутствовать в тексте:

```
rules = [re.compile(pattern).search
         for pattern in [r'\d', r'\W', r'\d{11}']]
rules += [lambda s, found=re.compile(antipattern).search: not found(s)
          for antipattern in [r'\d[.-]\d{2}[.-]\d']]
password_strength = sum(2 for matched in rules if matched(password))
```

### Negative lookahead assertion

Если запрещено отрицание в коде реализовать, но можно задать регулярное выражение для всего текста, тогда можно отрицательную опережающую (lookahead) проверку использовать:

```
not_found = re.fullmatch(r'(?:\D|\d(?![.-]\d{2}[.-]\d))*', text)
```

Словами: каждый символ во вводе либо не цифра (запрещённый шаблон начинается на цифру) либо цифра, за которой *не следует* остаток запрещённого шаблона.

### Создание руками обратного шаблона

Это самая сложная опция. Вот вариант, который пытается найти строки, которые не содержат `foo`, используя только один шаблон (без отрицания в коде, без lookahead): [Regex: Matching by exclusion, without look-ahead - is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/466053/4279)

[Представленное там решение](https://stackoverflow.com/a/466167/4279), не смотря на его трудночитаемость даже для такого тривиального случая (обратить `foo`), оказалось неверным (что только после 8 лет, 10000+ просмотров выяснилось).

То есть даже если это возможно сделать (руками реализацию negative lookahead для конечного шаблона явно выписать в виде regex), но результат будет трудно читаем и как следствие сложнее найти ошибки без исчерпывающего тестирования и сложнее будет изменить в будущем.